# PrimeFaces <p:cellEditor> not changing value of variable

Tags: primefaces, xhtml, jsf-2.2, tablecelleditor

I've done some research and haven't been able to find anything that directly addresses the problem I've been having.

I have a DataTable column that is editable (by cell) and I have the ability to click on the cell, enter a new number in the cell editor box, but when I hit the cell editor closes but does not save the new value (same thing happens if you just click off and don't hit enter).

Here is the Code Snippet

```
<h:form>
    <c:forEach items="#{extensionsBean.getPhases()}"  var="phase">
        <p:fieldset legend="#{phase.getPhaseName()}">
            <p:dataTable value="#{extensionsBean.getActivities(phase)}" var="activity" editable="true" editMode="cell">
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Actual Hours"/>
                    </f:facet>
                        <p:cellEditor>
                              <f:facet name="output">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{activity.getEstimateDetail().actualHours}"/>
                              </f:facet>
                              <f:facet name="input">
                                  <h:inputText value="#{activity.getEstimateDetail().actualHours}" />
                              </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                   //the rest of the closing tags are present
```

Any suggestions would be great! For the record, I have basically the exact same setup in a different xhtml page and I'm able to edit each of the cells without a problem. Not sure what's causing this one to bug out on me.

Answer (score 1):

Add Ajax event cellEdit and store the values

Comment: What exactly do you mean by store the values? Can you provide an example?

Comment: See the link for example: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

Add ajax event celledit and where do you want save the value you can save it. 
Code is below in my project

Xhtml page(Primefaces):

```
<p:dataTable var="my" value="#{java.custom_info}" editMode="cell" editable="true" style="font-size: 12px">

<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{java.custom_detail}"/>
<p:column style="background: white">
    <h:outputText value="First Name"/>
</p:column>
<p:column style="background: white">
  <p:cellEditor>
      <f:facet name="output"> <h:outputText value="#{my.first}"/>   </f:facet>
      <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{my.first}" placeholder="Enter First Name" style="width:93%"/></f:facet>
  </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

Java Class

```
public void custom_detail(CellEditEvent event){
    String old_str = (String) event.getOldValue();
    String first_name = (String) event.getNewValue();
    System.out.println("update method reached..."+first_name);
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    Query db = new Query();
    Customer bean = new Customer();
    if(session!=null){
        if(((String)session.getAttribute("login"))!=null){
            Calendar currentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            String datenow=format.format(currentDate.getTime());
            session.setAttribute("firstname", first_name);
            session.setAttribute("modified_date",datenow);
            bean.setFirst(first_name);
            bean.setUsrid((String)session.getAttribute("user"));
            bean.setUsr_modified(datenow);
            db.update_personalinfo(bean);   
      }
    } 
}
```